# non-GTK style broken in QT5 applications after ibus, gir, dconf install

Tags: kubuntu, qt, ibus, dconf, kde5

I installed IBUS and its dependencies. The following is an extract of `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

```
Start-Date: 2015-10-31  14:43:54
Install: gir1.2-atk-1.0:amd64 (2.16.0-2build1, automatic), gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.10-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64 (1.36.8-3, automatic), gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.16.7-0ubuntu3, automatic), ibus-pinyin:amd64 (1.5.0-3ubuntu3), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.32.1-1, automatic), python-xdg:amd64 (0.25-4, automatic), gir1.2-freedesktop:amd64 (1.44.0-1, automatic), ibus:amd64 (1.5.10-1ubuntu1, automatic), libpyzy-1.0-0v5:amd64 (1.0.1-4.1, automatic), dconf-cli:amd64 (0.24.0-2, automatic), libopencc1:amd64 (0.4.3-2build1, automatic), liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.4-1, automatic), pinyin-database:amd64 (1.2.99-3)
End-Date: 2015-10-31  14:44:26
```

Right after login back in, I am unable to set the widget style of qt4 apps in Kubuntu Wily 15.10 using the KDE `systemsettings`, `qtconfig-qt4` or `qtconfig` (executed as super-user) interface. The kde-style is set to`GTK+` by some qt5 apps (see picture below)

- Konsole (Qt 5.4.2, KDE Frameworks 5.15.0)
- Muon (Qt 5.4.2, KDE Frameworks 5.15.0)
- Kate and Systemsettings ... (same version)

The style is set correctly for the applications

- KTorrent (4.3.1, KDE Development Platform 4.14.13)
- Amarok (2.8.0, KDE 4.14.13)

I purged the packages I installed above but after relogin, the problem persists.

### Debugging

The configuration file `~.config/Trolltech.conf` mentions

```
[qt]
...
style=Breeze
...
```

I renamed the file. `~/.config` didn't contain other interesting files. I cleaned my `~/.local`, `~/.cache`, `~/.kde` folders and restarted my desktop manager. Did I miss a configuration file?

Which integration packages should I remove that may cause this problem?

[image: muon]